# How to get a list in pydantic basesetings

Tags: python, pydantic

This is the class I wrote for manage -

```py
class EnvSettings(BaseSettings):
    debug: bool = False
    secret_key: str
    allowed_hosts: str
    db_name: str
    db_user: str
    db_password: str
    db_host: str
    db_port: str
    minio_endpoint: str
    minio_access_key: str
    minio_secret_key: str
    minio_use_https: bool = False
    minio_media_bucket_name: str
    minio_static_bucket_name: str
    minio_media_url: str
    minio_static_url: str
    celery_broker_url: str
    celery_task_default_queue: str = 'default'
```

I want to get a list of strings for allowed hosts. How can I do it?

I already tried `allowed_hosts: List[str]`

This is the error it returned -
`pydantic_settings.sources.SettingsError: error parsing value for field "allowed_hosts" from source "EnvSettingsSource"`

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: I did but I couldn't found solution

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us the minimal code needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: Ali, did you find a solution? I have the same issue and can't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:
allowed_hosts: str= Field(default=['localhost, 127.0.0.1'])

```
### config.py ### 

class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls not in cls._instances:
        instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls._instances[cls] = instance
    return cls._instances[cls]


class CombinedMeta(SingletonMeta, type(BaseSettings)):
    pass


class Settings(BaseSettings, metaclass=CombinedMeta):
    fastapi_env: str = Field(default='Development')
    fastapi_debug: bool = Field(default=False)
    fastapi_host: str = Field(default='0.0.0.0')
    fastapi_run_port: int = Field(default=5000)
    app_secret_key: str = Field(default='GDtfDCFYjD')
    dict_http_msg: CustomMessages = CustomMessages()
    dict_api_header: CustomAPIHeader = CustomAPIHeader()
    allowed_hosts: str= Field(default=['localhost, 127.0.0.1'])
    aws_region_name: str = Field(default='us-east-1')
    aws_profile_name: str = Field(default='admpddcoredev')

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file=".env")

    @lru_cache
    def get_settings(self):
    return self

###

### app.py ###

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn

from ext.config import Settings
from controllers.appController import AppController

settings = Settings()


def create_app():
    app = FastAPI()
    app.secret_key = settings.app_secret_key
    app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=settings.allowed_hosts,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*']
    )
    AppController().init_app(app)

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()

    fastapi_env = settings.fastapi_env.lower()
    host = settings.fastapi_host
    port = settings.fastapi_run_port

    uvicorn.run(
    "app:create_app",
    host=host,
    port=port,
    reload=(fastapi_env != 'production') and settings.fastapi_debug
    )

###
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Pydantic do you use? I just tried your example with v2.5.3, and I don't get an error. So, this works:

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
from typing import List


class EnvSettings(BaseSettings):
    debug: bool = False
    secret_key: str
    allowed_hosts: List[str]


e = EnvSettings(secret_key="foo", allowed_hosts=["bar", "baz"])
```